# Need one help regarding fetching data value from response

Tags: rest

Need one help regarding fetching data value from response.

Below is my response which I got after hitting URL.

```
{
 "response": {
   "Error Message": "Invalid Input missing",
   "success": "false""
 }
}
```

In this I want to read "Error Message" through POSTMAN test. For same reason I have written below code, but it is not working due to space between key.

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests ["Verify Error message"] = data.response.Error Message==="Invalid Input - Mandatory data(Company ID/source Id/SalesRep Ids/ContactPerson Ids) missing";
```

Comment: in rest, you sholud get response code like 500,404. this will be easy for you to detect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `Error Message` as a field with a space in it. Try:

```
tests ["Verify Error message"] = data.response.["Error Message"]==="Invalid Input - Mandatory data(Company ID/source Id/SalesRep Ids/ContactPerson Ids) missing";
```

Comment: HI Alex,

Working fine for me. just made little correction.
tests ["Verify Error message"] = data.response["Error Message"]==="Invalid Input - Mandatory data(Company ID/source Id/SalesRep Ids/ContactPerson Ids) missing";

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is not good to compare string.
In your response you must have like this,

```
{
 "response": {
   "Error Message": "Invalid Input missing",
   "success": "false",
   "responseCode" : 400
 }
}
```

for more response codes, please go to this link,

http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml

Then after do comparison,

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
if(data.reponse.responseCode == '400'){
// do stuff
}
```